# How to convert a dataframe column to date-time format to plot a timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a column in my dataframe with values similar to this

```
"2017-09-27 06:32:27:919"
```

I tried to convert it to datetime using `pandas to_datettime` function. But it is not getting converted. What has to be done?I gave `unit='ns'` still it is not getting converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last `:` is causing the issue. Replace it with `.` prior to the convert.

Assuming your time column is `df.time`,

```
df['ns'] = df.time.apply(lambda x: x[-3:]) #make up ns column
df.time = df.time.apply(lambda x: str(x)[:-4] + ".") # cut off ns and replace ":" with "."
df.time = df.time + df.ns # combine above 2
df.drop('ns', axis=1, inplace=True) # we no longer need "ns" column
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, unit='ns') # Now you can convert time to "ns"
```

Comment: yw,... as a side note, if # of last digits are always 3 digits, I highly suspect that is mili second rather than nano second. In that case, `unit='ms'` is more proper than `unit='ns'`

Comment: OK..thats a nice obsrvation anyway,, I will take it into consideration,thanks buddy

Comment: I tried..but its saying ValueError: non convertible value 2017-09-25 22:32:21.030 with the unit 'ms'

Comment: Ok, preceding `0` may be the problem in that case... how about starting with `df['ns'] = df.time.apply(lambda x: str(int(x[-3:])))`? Does it work with `unit='ms'`?

Comment: I did rethink and noticed that actually with `unit=ns` as it is OK to express `ms` because we can regard that 3 digits as upper 3 digits below decimal. You can verify this by comparing results by 2 different codes starting with `df['ns'] = df.time.apply(lambda x: '000000' + x[-3:])` and `df['ns'] = df.time.apply(lambda x: x[-3:] + '000000')`. Does it make sense?